# Laravel setLocale returns stored value but use config.app default one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-localization

I am getting some strange problem... as title said...

I am making post request to change lang value by setting lang forever cookie.

After that I am checking if cookie exist and if it does to `app()->setLocale(\Cookie::get('lang'))` and then use `{{ app()->getLocale() }}` which returns stored lang value as **en** or **fr**.

But still page is loading `config/app.php => 'locale'=>'en'`...

Can I at least change `config('app.locale') value to \Cookie::get('lang')` or do you know what can be a problem here?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I found the answer, I need to add to every file inside views folder - new locale value to be able to retrieve right lang content.. I don't know why because I never had problem before but if somebody else have problem this may be solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you change the locale not in the right place. You should use `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` to do that.

Innside `boot` method you could add something like this:

```
$this->app->setLocale(\Cookie::get('lang', 'en')
```

And then you will have language set all the time - when cookie is set to the value from cookie, otherwise to `en`

Then in your view you don't need to do anything. You can just use:

```
{{ trans('some.translated') }}
```

and it will be translated into valid language when you set translation in translation files.

Comment: Whats is the difference between __('something') and trans('something') ?

Comment: @StupidKid `__` first reads from Json translations and then from array format, and `trans` only loads array translations

Comment: Okay enough to accept the answer, btw I totally forgot for boot method.. Can I pass through boot some model used on every page and view on the app?

Comment: For this you should rather use https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers or take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#passing-data-to-views

Answer (score 0):

The `app()->setLocale('fr')` will change the locale for the duration of the request to 'fr'. So if after setting it, you call `app()->getLocale()`, it will return 'fr'.

If your application reads locale from `config('app.locale')` in some places, you can change the value on the go like this:

```
config(['app.locale' => 'fr'])
```

Then the `config('app.locale')` will return 'fr' for the duration of the request

Comment: I found that and I did it but I found also that setLocale is being set in my master.blade which is as template for every page, but on other sections like if I call getLocale from other sections from other files like home.blade which extends master locale is back to en....

Comment: Thats for both config.app.locale and fot app()->setLocale() they are only set in master file but others which are extending master file are back to default one...

Comment: I found answer, but I never had problem with this like this.... It seems that for each file in views I need to setLocale to cookie value....

Comment: I recommend setting the locale with middleware, then all views should be affected

Comment: Can you post me an example, it's true I haven't sleep whole night and my brain is off but I would like to accept your answer as well :D